# How to efficiently get spsite in a farm with 20000 site collections in powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to see if I some sites match my criteria. First I need to find the count number, and then print some properties

However this query, is taking 10 minutes for every row in the csv file. I wonder if there is a faster way to do it.

```
$clientcode = @()
$ProspectClientCode = @()

    Import-Csv C:\Users\usern\Downloads\user.csv |`
        ForEach-Object {
            $clientcode = $_.clientcode
            $ProspectClientCode = $_.ProspectClientCode
            Write-Host "Processing ClientCode: " + $_.clientcode + ", Prospect Code: " + $_.ProspectClientCode
            $count = (Get-SPSite -Limit All | where { $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"] -eq $clientCode -or $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"] -eq $ProspectClientCode}).Count
            Write-Host "Sites found: " + $count
            Get-SPSite -Limit All | where { $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"] -eq $clientCode -or $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"] -eq $ProspectClientCode} | select Url, {$_.RootWeb.Created}, {$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"]}, {$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientName"]} , {$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientSiteCode"]}
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting ALL sites, twice, for each csv entry. I'd try to first get all sites, assign it to a variable and then filter it inside the loop. That said, there might better ways to get a filtered query on the server side but I don't know if there a way.

```
$sites = Get-SPSite -Limit All

Import-Csv C:\Users\usern\Downloads\user.csv | ForEach-Object {

    $clientcode = $_.ClientCode
    $ProspectClientCode = $_.ProspectClientCode

    $created = @{n='Created';e={$_.RootWeb.Created}}
    $clientCode = @{n='ClientCode ';e={$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"]}}
    $clientName = @{n='ClientName ';e={$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientName"]}}
    $clientSiteCode = @{n='ClientSiteCode';e={$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientSiteCode"]}}

    $sites | 
    where { $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"] -eq $ClientCode -or $_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"] -eq $ProspectClientCode} |
    select Url,$created,$clientCode,$clientName,$clientSiteCode 
}
```

Comment: can u please explain me the syntax of lines like these: $clientCode = @{n='ClientCode ';e={$_.RootWeb.AllProperties["ClientCode"]}}
     its confusing for me!

Comment: Instead of writing those inline, I'm creating the hashtables and assign them to a variable, then you can pass the variable to the select-object cmdlet. It's just another way of writing the same, but it's more readable.